# Why can't Rust use the size of a generic parameter as an array length?

Tags: templates, generics, rust, compile-time

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the problem with this code:

```
fn doesnt_compile<T>() {
    println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<[T; std::mem::size_of::<T>()]>());
}

fn main() {
    doesnt_compile::<i32>();
}
```

When run in the playground (or on my machine) the compiler seems to ignore the implicit trait bound 'Sized' for T.

This is the error:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `T` cannot be known at compilation time
   --> src/main.rs:2:64
    |
2   |     println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<[T; std::mem::size_of::<T>()]>());
    |                                                                ^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
    |
    = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `T`
    = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
    = help: consider adding a `where T: std::marker::Sized` bound
```

I stared at it for a while and tried to rewrite it in different ways, but i can't figure out why it shouldn't compile. I find it especially confusing since the following code works just fine:

```
fn compiles<T>() {
    println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<T>());
}

fn main() {
    compiles::<i32>();
}
```

Is there something I'm missing? Is it a compiler bug?

Comment: This looks like a compiler bug to me. I'm not sure yet whether the code should compile, but the error message definitely looks wrong.

Comment: Interesting; I tried lifting the `size_of::<T>()` into a `const` and was met with another error -- that `const` items cannot use the generic parameters from the outer functions, which make sense for `fn`/`type` items but definitely not for `const`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. That is actually expected behaviour, though the error message could be improved.

Comment: As a side note, the `Sized` bound on `T` is redundant. All type parameters have an implicit `Sized` bound. If you want to allow unsized types, you need to override that implicit bound with `T: ?Sized`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yeah I had put it there due to the compiler error stating that T did not satisfy Sized. I'll rephrase the question and correct the code.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: I would say that this is *known* behavior, yet unexpected. Unlike a `fn` or `type`, you cannot have a generic `const` item, and thus a `const` item need be able to access its outer function (or struct, or impl) generic parameters. I'm happy to write it off as a limitation for now, but longer term it will need to be fixed.

Comment: With [const generics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2000-const-generics.md) enabled, right now the closest I can get it to work is [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8e583172c05dca97b9c8c6790433c7ba).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the result of a [known compiler bug (#43408)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43408). Array length expressions cannot currently have type parameters, and apparently it isn't even possible to improve the error message without major refactoring.

There currently isn't a good workaround for this in general, though there might be one for your specific use case.

Comment: I don't think it is directly related with an array length expressions, it is a constant evaluation issue(it happens on array, because it expects a generic constant), please see : https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=209509470bd94a493c0a106cda06ddea

Comment: @ÖmerErden Quoting one of the compiler devs from the linked bug: "This is a limitation of array length - it can't use any parameters in scope - which also came up during the stabilization of associated consts." I'm not sure whether it actually is the same issue, but based on that quote I decided to phrase my answer this way.

Comment: Sure, i had no intention to disprove your answer, instead i was trying to point [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59388990/why-cant-rust-determine-the-size-of-a-template-parameter-at-compile-time/59389732?noredirect=1#comment104969111_59388990). The actual error can be from **Constant Evaluation**.

Comment: Once you know the answer, please search for existing questions / answers that have already provided the answer. This reduces our maintenance burden of keeping older questions and answers updated.